# Problem with recognising attributes inside a function

Tags: python, bash, function, parameters, shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#!/config.py
_UNIGENE_DIR = "/data/PROGRAMMING/assignment5"
_UNIGENE_FILE_ENDING = "unigene"

    def get_unigene_directory (self,_UNIGENE_DIR) :
        """Returns the absolute path"""
        self._UNIGENE_DIR = _UNIGENE_DIR
        print(self._UNIGENE_DIR)

   def get_uigene_extension(self,_UNIGENE_FILE_ENDING) :
       """Returns the extension of the file"""
       self._UNIGENE_FILE_ENDING = _UNIGENE_FILE_ENDING
       print(self_UNIGENE_FILE_ENDING)
```

So, when I run the folowing command in the python environment of my bash:

```py
      file = "/".join( (config.get_unigene_directory(), host, gene + "." + 
      config.get_unigene_extension() ) )
```

I get the following error:

```py
     TypeError: get_unigene_directory() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 
     '_UNIGENE_DIR'.May I know whats the reason for this error?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know how functions work in Python. I suggest you take a look into this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

Basically, if you declare a function with one or more parameters, you need to pass them when you call it.

Another thing, you can't use **self** outside a class. This keyword refers to the actual class the method is in.

Comment: Right but when I pass it like this:  _UNIGENE_DIR = "/data/PROGRAMMING/assignment5"
   _UNIGENE_FILE_ENDING = "unigene"
  
   def get_unigene_directory () :
      """Returns the absolute path"""
      return (_UNIGENE_DIR)
 
    def get_uigene_extension() :
     """Returns the extension of the file"""
     return (_UNIGENE_FILE_ENDING) ,